# How to rename many xml files with certain element inside them?

Tags: xml, rename, element

I have many xml files in one folder

[image]

I need to rename them to be whatever inside NENAME element to be --> 4thBridge_KRK4063.xml , this is the part in a file for example:

[image]

```
<class>
        <NE>
            <attributes>
                <LOCATION></LOCATION>
                <SWVERSION>BTS3900_5900 V100R015C10SPC210</SWVERSION>
                <USERLABEL></USERLABEL>
                <NERMVERSION>3900BTSDATAV100R015C10SPC210</NERMVERSION>
                <INTERFACEID>BTS3900 V100R015C10SPC210</INTERFACEID>
                <PRODUCTVERSION>BTS3900 V100R015C10SPC210</PRODUCTVERSION>
                <LMTVERSION>BTS3900 V100R015C10SPC210</LMTVERSION>
                <DID></DID>
                <SITENAME></SITENAME>
                <NENAME>4thBridge_KRK4063</NENAME>
                <HOTPATCHVERSION>BTS3900_5900 V100R015C10SPH213</HOTPATCHVERSION>
                <CLOUDBBID>0</CLOUDBBID>
            </attributes>
        </NE>
    </class>
```

I don't know much about programming so kindly advise.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an XSLT 3.0 processor such as Saxon:

```
<xsl:transform
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:param name="inputDir"/>
  <xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:for-each select="collection($inputDir || '?select=*.xml')">
      <xsl:result-document href="{//NENAME}.xml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I downloaded both saxon HE/ saxon resources but I'm a bit lost, where can I enter this code?

Comment: If you're running from the command line, use a command like `java net.sf.saxon.Transform -xsl:style.xsl -it:main inputDir=myInputDir`, where style.xsl holds the stylesheet code above and myInputDir is the directory containing the input files. But if you're not comfortable with use of the command line, you might prefer to download a GUI tool such as the Oxygen IDE. I'm afraid whatever approach you take, when you start to use new tools there is a learning curve (and a lot of documentation to read).

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!